# PowerShell comparison of partial string confusion

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements

I have a set of partial job titles in an array that I'm trying to compare to someone's full title in [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) (AD). `-like` and `-match`, as well as all the others, aren't working.

```
[string[]]$Titles =@('genetic','medic','nurs','optome','perfusion','pharm','phys')

($titles -like $user.Title) - nope
($user.title -contains $titles) - nope
($Titles.Contains($user.title)) - nope
```

I need a user title, "Physician", to match up with "phys". Why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you (seem to) want, iterate ("loop") over each title in `$Titles` and compare the `$User.Title` property to each individual partial title, and then see if any of them returned `$true`:

```
foreach($User in Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Title){
    $TitleFound = @($Titles |ForEach-Object {$User.Title -like "$_*"} ) -contains $true
    if($TitleFound){
        Do-Stuff
    }
}
```

---

That being said, you may want to use the partial strings to build an [LDAP Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx) string, that way the Domain Controller can take care of the filtering instead of returning all the users.

I LDAP search filter syntax, your query would look like this:

```
(|(title=genetic*)(title=medic*)(title=nurs*)(title=optome*)(title=perfusion*)(title=pharm*)(title=phys*))
```

You could generate that from your string array, with `ForEach-Object`:

```
# The | prefix means "or", as in "if any of these statements are true", return the object
$FilterTemplate = '(|{0})' 

# This will be the comparison statements inside the filter
$FilterCriteria = $Titles |Foreach-Object { '(title={0}*)' -f $_ }

# Now put it all together
$LDAPFilter = $FilterTemplate -f -join($FilterCriteria)

# And retrieve the users:
$MedicalStaff = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $LDAPFilter -Properties Title
```

Comment: Thanks again Mathias. The first part is exactly what I'm looking for!